# Automating apple pay integration in mobile web with safari browser

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ios-simulator, appium-ios, applepay

I got a requirement to integrate Apple pay to our E-commerce website. This is intended only to run in safari mobile browsers. I am in search for a way to automate the apple pay integration. We will have an option from cart page to choose Apple pay. Once user selects this a panel is displayed which have options to select the saved credit card, addresses in the mobile phone (we call this as apple payment sheet). These informations are prefilled but user can change this. I believe this is some kind of native code which displays this panel above the safari. I need to device an end-to-end test which has both normal web simulation and the payment sheet simulation so that it could complete an order successfully.

For this, I have few roadblocks:

1. We need a common tool which can simulate user interaction in mobile web (this is currently done by webdriverIO) and the payment sheet provided by safari for apple pay(No idea how to inspect or simulate user interaction on this panel).

2.We need to simulate fingerprint authorization from the test automation tool. I am still to get a solution for this. Have considered many tools but found out that none of them can help. Not sure about the capabilities of Appium in this regard. It would be of great help if someone can point me in the right direction of choice of tool that can be used here.

Comment: Till this date there is no way to  automate Apple Pay.